# Right inputs but incorrect output when reading though a file in C

Tags: c, file, struct

I have a struct that is supposed to contain a word, its corresponding number, and its clue.

```
struct Word{
    char word[30];
    int level;
    char clue[500];
};
typedef struct Word Word;
```

I manipulate it through the following functions.

```
void createWord(){ //creates a word

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("words.bin", "a+"); 

    if(!fp){
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }else{

        Word w;

        w.level = getLevel(); //gets level number in the list

        getchar();
        printf("Enter word: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", w.word); //asks for the word

        getchar();
        printf("Enter clue: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", w.clue); //asks for the clue
        getchar();
        
        //i used this to trace the values
        printf("\n%d", w.level);
        printf("\n%s", w.word);
        printf("\n%s", w.clue);
        
        //goes through the file and writes the content in it
        fseek(fp, sizeof(Word)*(w.level - 1), SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&w, sizeof(Word),1, fp);

        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

```
int getLevel(){

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("words.bin", "r");

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    int n = ftell(fp)/sizeof(Word); //tells me the number of 'Words' that are already in the file
    fclose(fp);

    return n++;
}
```

```
void displayContent(){ //displays all the content inside the file

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("words.bin", "rb");

    if(!fp){
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }else{
        Word w;
        while(fread(&w, sizeof(Word), 1, fp) && !feof(fp)){
            printf("\n");
            printWord(&w);
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
}

void printWord(struct Word *w){

    printf("Level: %d\n", w->level+1);
    printf("Word: %s\n", w->word);
    printf("Clue: %s\n", w->clue);
}
```

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
int main(){

    int choice;

    Word w;
    do{

        printf("\n\n1. Create Word\n");
        printf("2. Diplay all words\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");
        printf("\n? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                createWord();
                break;

            case 2:
                displayContent();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }while(choice != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

My main problem is the fact that I enter the right values. Whenever I check it before going out the function, it reads right. However, when I try to display all of the contents in the file, the output are completely wonky. Here's an example.

```
Level: 1 //this one is correct
Word: Uno
Clue: The grade our teacher will give us by the end of the semester.


Level: 257 //this one is not, this is supposed to be 2
Word: vBo Burnham // this is supposed to be Bo Burnham only
Clue: //and this is supposed to print a sentence like 'Go listen to his new album'
```

I think it has something to do with `getchar()` but I'm not really sure as well. Any form of help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `return n++` looks wrong. That will return the value that `n` was **before** incrementing it. I'm guessing you actually want `return (n+1)`

Comment: The first time you call `getLevel` it will return 0 and then the `fseek` in `createWord` will go to `-sizeof(Word)`. Consider changing `return n++;` to `return n + 1;` in `getLevel`.

Comment: A study of how `scanf` works is time well spent. The `"%[^\n]s"` is a common error, a hybrid of two distinct format specifiers `%[]` and `%s`. Also how it handles whitespace (not the same for all formats), because you have sprinkled the code with `getchar()`, a kludge which is usually unnecessary. Also, in `printf` the newline output is usually placed last, not first.

Comment: Please note the behaviour whren a file is opened in `"a+"` mode: *When a file is opened by using the "a" access type or the "a+" access type, **all write operations occur at the end of the file**. The file pointer can be repositioned by using fseek or rewind, but is **always moved back to the end of the file before any write operation** is performed. Therefore, existing data cannot be overwritten.* So, the `fseek()` before the `fwrite()` does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void createWord(){

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("words.bin", "a+");

    if(!fp){
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }else{

        Word w;
        char tempWord[30];
        char tempClue[100];
        int tempNum;

        tempNum = getLevel();

        fgetc(stdin);

        printf("Enter word: ");
        fgets(tempWord, 30, stdin);
        tempWord[strlen(tempWord)-1] = 0;

        printf("Enter clue: ");
        fgets(tempClue, 100, stdin);
        tempClue[strlen(tempClue) - 1] = 0;

        w.level = tempNum;
        strcpy(w.word, tempWord);
        strcpy(w.clue, tempClue);

        printf("\n%d", w.level);
        printf("\n%s", w.word);
        printf("\n%s", w.clue);

        fwrite(&w, sizeof(Word), 1, fp);

        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

The `\n` made it wonky. It still is kind of right now but it works.